# NullPointerEx. caused by NullPointerEx. caused by NullPointerEx

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I get this weird exception I try to run my Android application. I'm using a normal Activity-class and I've managed to get a ListView up a working. I've added a onClickListerner to the listitems. I've got this error message several times on various occasions.

Why are the exceptions chained?

```
cause  NullPointerException  (id=830007823976)  
    -> cause    NullPointerException  (id=830007823976) 
        -> cause    NullPointerException  (id=830007823976) 
            -> cause    NullPointerException  (id=830007823976) 
                -> cause    NullPointerException  (id=830007823976) 
                detailMessage   null    
                stackState   (id=830007824008)  
                stackTrace  null    
             .....
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the IDs are all the same - non-chained exceptions have themselves as the cause. There is only one `NullPointerException` here, so your task is to find the line where a null value is being dereferenced, and how it got there.

Comment: Exactly.  What else could it be other than a NullPointer in the first error location? (To think that the Java language creators thought that eliminating pointers would avoid all such problems!)